# why we need ViewGroup parameter on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

i work in RecyclerView and i have this method :

```
 // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

i need clear explain about this parameter `parent` why should we use it and what is the purpose ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you should really ask is:

> Why do we need to pass in the parent when inflating a view?

When you have created your `my_text_view` layout it probably had some XML that looked something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
```

As you can see quite a few Android attributes start `layout_`.  This means that they are part of the `LayoutParams` for that view.  When Android does the layout it evaluates these in relation to the parent of the view.  It is possible to inflate a view without passing in a parent:

```
LayoutInflater
    .from(parent.getContext())
    .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, null);
```

If you do this however then any `layout_` attributes that you have specified in your XML are just thrown away.  This can cause your layout to appear differently from what might have been expected.

> Why are we using parent.getContext() rather than the activity context

You could use the Activity context and most of the time it will not make any difference.  The parent will most likely have inherited its `context` from the Activity.

However it is possible that the parent has modified the context, for example by assigning a different theme to it.

Comment: i search about parent parameter and i found that RecyclerView always passes itself as the parent view , and this explain what LayoutParams means in this context, the inflated layout will take LayoutParams of RecyclerView, is this what happened really??

Comment: The inflated layout will use the values (width, height, etc) the RecyclerView (parent) gives it to calculate its LayoutParams

Comment: another note about context ,you say that no difference between view Context and activity Context, i referred to android documentation and View does not inherit Context class so there is different right!!

Comment: `View` does not inherit `Context`.  However a `View` class has a `Context` as one of its member variables.  This is set in its constructor and is normally the Activity Context

Answer (score 0):

According to the [[docs]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

> A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called
>   children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views
>   containers. This class also defines the ViewGroup.LayoutParams class
>   which serves as the base class for layouts parameters.

ie The `ViewGroup` is an invisible container that can hold both `View`s as well as `ViewGroup`s.  For eg: LinearLayout is the ViewGroup that contains Button(View), and other Layouts .

[image]

And the purpose of `ViewGroup` in `onCreateViewHolder()` is when an item in a `RecyclerView` require a specific `ViewGroup` to be represented. For this purpose you can either create a new View manually or inflate it from an XML layout file. As in your code, you are inflating from xml:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
```

And the new ViewHolder will be used to display items of the adapter using `onBindViewHolder()` later on.

Comment: as you can see you pass false in inflate( ) this mean the returned View not associated with this parent !!

Comment: another note please ! why we using parent.getContext() rather than passing activity context as ListView??